# Swift UIGestureRecognizer Touchdown

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to capture touchdown and longpress with UIGestureRecognizer?

```
func gestureSetup() {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapButton:")
    tapTempoButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    tapTempoButton.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
}

func tapButton(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   // On touch down update UI and play sound
}
```

Comment: yes, You can add all of the Gestures on one object if you wanted to. What are you trying to accomplish. On a button, label, UIImageView?

Answer (score 1):

example: Gestures on UITextLabel
        //Called on Label
        let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleRotation:")
        rotationGesture.delegate = self

```
    let tapToDeleteTextGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapToDeleteText:")
    tapToDeleteTextGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

   textLabel?.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
    textLabel?.addGestureRecognizer(tapToDeleteTextGesture)


func handleRotation(recognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer){
    let state = recognizer.state
    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began || state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed){
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, recognizer.rotation)
            recognizer.rotation = 0
        }
    }
}

 func tapToDeleteText(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Add add the longPressGesture and you'll be set.